# disable previous date and change date format in magento2

Tags: datepicker, magento2

I have added a new module for delivery date but how to change date format and disable previous date.

Below is the URL that I have using.

http://oyenetwork.com/articles/magento2-devliery-date-module-creation-from-scratch/

Comment: I am also facing same issue